# (A) burden (to / on) someone

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

As you know, the word "[burden](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/burden)" depending on context, can convey various meanings. One of its connotations is "something difficult or worrying that you are responsible for", which is in my question.
I was wondering which choice below sounds more idiomatic to you:

> - I have three unemployed sons sitting at home. I have to work in my 70s to put bread on their table. They are...........

a. a burden to me 
b. burdens to me 
c. a burden on me 
d. burdens on me

Whereas the word "burden" is a countable noun here, and the subject of the sentence refers to three youths which are actin as dead-weights to their father, to me, the most natural one is "d", however I have no idea whether the other options would work here or there is something the matter with them which I need to be aware of.

Please kindly explain that to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either "burden" or "burdens" fits. It's a question of how the speaker is thinking of them, and I don't see any reason to choose one over the other, given just that sentence.

As to the prepositions, saying "They are a burden **on** me." is a simple statement about how they weigh on me.

Saying "They are a burden **to** me." is a statement about how I regard them, that is, what they mean to me.

The difference is subtle, and doesn't change the meaning much, if at all.